# SQL: Statement only returns subtotal of the first row

Tags: mysql, sql

I have Sample Data like below:
[image: Sample Data]

and i use the below SQL statement :

```
select a.product_category_id, b.Favorite, c.In_Cart,d.Pre_sales_order,
       sum(b.Favorite)+sum(c.In_Cart)+sum(d.Pre_sales_order) as SubTotal
from 
    (select distinct product_category_id 
     from item_activity 
    where last_item_status_code in (6,7,8)
) a
left join
    (select product_category_id, count(last_item_status_code) as Favorite
     from .item_activity  
     where last_item_status_code='6' 
     group by product_category_id
) b   on a.product_category_id=b.product_category_id
left join
  (select product_category_id, count(product_category_id) as In_Cart 
   from item_activity  
   where last_item_status_code='7' 
   group by product_category_id
) c on c.product_category_id=a.product_category_id 
left join
   (select product_category_id, count(product_category_id) as Pre_sales_order 
    from item_activity  
    where last_item_status_code='8' 
    group by product_category_id
) d on d.product_category_id=a.product_category_id 
group by a.product_category_id
;
```

and achieved this:
[image: result]

But it just give me the subtotal of the first row....

Comment: Okay, now that we can actually read your question we can finally start to help you. Only 5 minutes in, so you only missed about 1/2 of your potential front page audience. In the future, remember that more effort to the question before you post will make a huge difference in the number of people who might be able to help.

Comment: Also, we **much** prefer text for the sample data and results. Images are considered rude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select product_category_id,
   sum(case when last_item_status_code=6 then 1 else 0 end) As Favorite,
   sum(case when last_item_status_code=7 then 1 else 0 end) As In_Cart,
   sum(case when last_item_status_code=8 then 1 else 0 end) As Pre_sales_order,
   count(last_item_status_code) as SubTotal
from item_activity
where last_item_status_code in (6,7,8)
group by product_category_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

the product_category_id doesn't exist in other tables. So the Subtotal is resulting to NULL.

SUM(1 + NULL) == NULL. You can use IF or COALESCE to convert NULL to 0.